# Tastypie: Filter Django comments based on the commented object

Tags: django, tastypie

I use the django comments from contrib and I have an object (entry) that has some comments associated with it. In my tastypie resources I have:

```
class CommentResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

class Meta:
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'comments'
    allowed_methods = ['get']
    fields = ['comment', 'resource_uri', 'submit_date', 'user',]
    filtering = {
        'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
    }
```

and I can get all the comments, or filter them by user. It's working ok.
Now I'm not sure, how would I do the same kind of filter but based on a certain entry object instead of user?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I do not follow: "_how would I do the same kind of filter but based on a certain entry object instead of user_"? Which entry object? Could you clarify / elaborate?

Comment: I have a model called 'entry'. Right now the filter returns all comments for 'user', I'd like the same kind of behavior but using that 'entry' model instead of 'user'. But I don't know how to do that since 'user' is a foreignkey of 'Comment' but 'entry' has nothing to do with 'Comment'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what is the relationship between the `entry` and `comment` it is hard to give a concrete answer but in a nut shell given that entry and comments are linked via manytomany relationship:

- Create an EntryResource
- Add the `fields.ToManyField` to the EntryResource for CommentResource
- Add the `fields.ToOneField' to the CommentResource for EntryResource
- Add `'comments' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS` to the filtering dict in `EntryResource`

Additionally, you could add a nested resource or a custom URL to the Comment to filter them based on an entry, but it all depends on your design.

Almost verbatim example for the above is given in Tastypie docs [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#reverse-relationships).

Comment: I use the comment app from Django , the relationship is the default. Thanks for your explanation and link to the docs, it helps a lot.